# Forward SSH traffic from public IP to local IP

Tags: ssh, iptables, routing, firewall, port-forwarding

I need to find a way to forward ssh traffic from a WAN ip address to a specific host IP address on a local network. The set up is as follows:

WAN ---------|Firewall| ----SSH Machine

EXTERNAL         |      INTERNAL

Is there a way to make ssh connections from the firewall's external network adapter be forwarded to the SSH Machine?

Cheers!

Edit: the firewall that is being used is the one offered by Iptables. It has been configured to act as a router as well. The connection is being made by an external windows machine using command prompts SSH functionality

Comment: Welcome on U&L! What is that firewall? What operating system does it run? Which tools does it offer for configuring it? Please, [add](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/615845/edit) this information to your question.

Answer (score 0):

To preface this, all information regarding this comes from [Daywalker's ServerFault answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/532569/how-to-do-port-forwarding-redirecting-on-debian)

All I've done is label this according to your use case.
An explanation from his post

> The first one specifies that all incoming tcp connections to port 1234 should be sent >to port 80 of the internal machine 192.168.57.25. This rule alone doesn’t complete the job because iptables denyes all incoming connections. Then we accept the incoming connection to port 1234 from eth3 which connect to the Internet with the publich IP by the second rule. We add the second rule in FORWARD chain to allow forwarding the packets to port 80 of 192.168.57.25.

In Reference to the Masquerade Rule:

> To keep track of the connection. otherwise the outside host would see the Internal IP 192.168.57.25 which he has no clue of.

```
   echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
   iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i <WAN INT> -p tcp --dport <WAN PORT> -j DNAT --to-destination <SSH MACHINE IP>:22
   iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d <SSH MACHINE IP> --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
   iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -s <SSH MACHINE IP> -o <WAN INT> -j MASQUERADE
```